# stored procedures without parameters in 10g

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures

To display my name using procedure

```
create or replace procedure auto is
  vname varchar(20) :='manish';
 begin 
 dbms_output.put_line('what is my name?'||vname);
end auto;
```

Procedure compilled sucessfully but cant set serveroutput on please help. I am using oracle 10g

Comment: What do you mean by you can't set server output on? How are you calling the procedure?

Comment: you can add BEGIN dbms_output.enable(); see google

Comment: tell me how to call i am having trouble i am new to oracle @ut

Comment: Retrieving and displaying the `dbms_output` buffer is up to the client. We would need to know which client you're using and how you're calling the procedure from it. (What does your question title have to do with what you're actually asking about?)

Comment: i need output as "whatis my name ? manish" how to make this possible

Comment: how do you execute it ? are you using PLSQL Developer? or SQL PLUS? other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For PL SQL Developer Client:

```
create or replace procedure auto is
  vname varchar(20) :='manish';
 begin 
 dbms_output.enable();
 dbms_output.put_line('what is my name?'||vname);
end auto;
```

to view output execute (right click on procedure and Test):

```
begin
  -- Call the procedure
  auto;
end;
```

and then click on DBMS Output tab

Comment: how to view output @user7294900

Comment: That will cause the buffer to be populated, it won't display anything to the screen unless the client looks at the buffer.